# Srop Back Button From Retuning To Top Of Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get the same behavior on mobile devices as I get from my desktop (pc) when navigation my discussion forum.... when using a pc, if I hit the browser's back button it returns me to the spot where I launched the page from, so, for example, it would return me to the middle of the previous page if that's where I happened to be before I navigated away from it.

But when I use a mobile device I'm returned to the top of the previous page when I hit the back button, not the location I launched from.

Is there a way to change this behavior and have it return to the spot I launched from? thanks very much!

Comment: What is your code so far ? What have you tried ?

Comment: @aeneas1 does my answer clear anything up, happy to answer any questions :)

Comment: very strange, i could have sworn that i had updated this post.... the problem was the body had a css height setting of 100%, i changed it to auto and nothing but pure love!